# What does "take stock of" mean here in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> By the divine is meant that which, being greater and more excellent than man, enjoins upon him, as he comes to a recognition of it, the need to take stock of his own shortcomings and enter into a new mode of being, wherein those shortcomings are somehow resolved or transcended. (*The Presocratics*, ed. by W. Philip)

Dictionaries say that "take stock of something" means to make an appraisal of it. But  I want to find what it literally means, and then figure out why it can be understood as explained in those dictionaries. So what does take stock of something literally mean?

By the way, some dictionaries say it is an American phrase, so how will Brits understand it?

Comment: Some dictionaries allow searching for phrases. ODO has [take stock](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stock?q=take+stock+of#stock__59). If that doesn't help, please edit the question to say why it doesn't; at the moment it appears to answer what you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

The historical root of this is from stock taking - counting or assessing the number of animals on your farm, or the number of items in stock in your shop etc.

So here you are appraising your stock - ie your list of shortcomings.